# Distance metric for dummy and continous variables

Tags: regression, machine-learning, distance, k-nearest-neighbour, euclidean

I'm trying to apply the KNN regression model to the data I have at my disposal which contains one dummy variable and two continuous variables (which I have normalized). I was wondering if it is okay to use the euclidean distance formula in this scenario. Or do I have to make some modifications due to the dummy variable.